# My navigation disappears in IE9 on hover on my image

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

i'm starting to learn, a bit on my own, to create a website. Now i have a problem i can't fix. I searched already on the internet but it doesn't work for me.
My navigation disappears when i hover. In some pages it only disappears when i hover my last link and other pages like [this one](http://www.villadurbuy.be/huisbeschrijving_Septon.html):  it disappears by the second link.
i'm starting to get a little hopeless to find a solution. That's why i ask for help!

Comment: I only tried on IE 9 and that doesn't work

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle example

Comment: [1]: http://www.villadurbuy.be/huisbeschrijving_Septon.html

Comment: It's the spaces between that's the problem.

Comment: Oké i try to create it..

Comment: @ Rachel Gallen I know it is a bad page, have to learn a lot but you had to see the previously website.. It was worse..
@MiniRagnarok witch spaces you mean exactly?

Comment: There's all kinds of problems. Run your site through a validator like http://validator.w3.org/ , fix those problems and see if you're still having problems.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok Already tried but, i'm sorry, i don't understand those solutions yet

Comment: @Dom This is what jsfiddle said:
Missing semicolon
Don't make functions within a loop
What does it mean? Thx

// JavaScript Document

/* the li:hover that makes the sub-menus appear means nothing to IE */

startList = function() {
if (document.all&&document.getElementById) {
navRoot = document.getElementById("nav");
for (i=0; i<navRoot.childNodes.length; i++) {
node = navRoot.childNodes[i];
if (node.nodeName=="LI") {
node.onmouseover=function() {
this.className+=" over";
  }
  node.onmouseout=function() {
  this.className=this.className.replace(" over", "");
   } } }}}
window.onload=startList;

Comment: The errors that they give you are the same errors that Jrod is telling you about. Are there specific lines you don't understand? For example, the first error says: "document type does not allow element "li" here; missing one of "ul", "ol" start-tag" somewhere around line 63. So I went there and I noticed that you're missing a bunch of end </li> tags.

Comment: How you say it i understand 'you're missing a bunch of end </li> tags.
I'll try it again and ask over here if i don't understand.. But the most important problem now is the navigation. People can not surf on our website and like that we can't put our vacationhouses for rent..

Comment: Internet explorer doesn't like it when you have errors. I know you see the navigation as number one but IE does strange things when you have missing closing tags. We really can't help you until they're all gone.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok Thx a lot! I'll do my best to solve them..

Comment: @MiniRagnarok I've solved them with the validator, it gives passe. The navigation still doesn't work..

Comment: Anyone who want's to help? i would appreciate..

Answer (score 3):

Remove the html from your `css/navigatie.css` stylesheet

It is the last line and looks like the following.

```
/* we need to associate the JavaScript with our main ul*/
<ul id="nav">
```

You have random `<tr>` and `<td>` tags in your html that should be removed at lines 92, 93, 155 and 156 as there is no table declared.

Line 140 an `<ol>` looks like it was closed with `</ul>`

Comment: Are you still having trouble with the navigation after fixing these errors?

Comment: yes i have.. I also fixed the problems who the validator give me and still doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

In the comments I mentioned that the spacing was your issue and you wanted clarification so here goes. Your navigation has nested lists, links, and images. For whatever reason they all have different heights. All I had to do to fix the problem was to make the nested `li` have a fixed height of `23px` and the problem went away.

Honestly, I would redo the navigation. I can't see a good reason why you have a class called `menu` being applied to every `ul` and `li` in the navigation. It should be really easy to change the heights of the different elements but the way that the navigation is set up I think you're going to have a rough time.